# how to autoscroll a list view in android?

Tags: android

how to autoscroll a list view in android?I am adding data to the list so i want that  when i add it should autoscroll and the last added item should be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function setSelectionFromTop(int position, int y)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelectionFromTop%28int,%20int%29

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But can you elaborate a bit.how will i get this Y??coordinates(0,0) start from above or below??.Is there any funtion which can tell which cordinates my list occupies

Comment: Just read the documentation: 
position: Index (starting at 0) of the data item (adapter) to be selected.
y: The distance from the top edge of the ListView (plus padding) that the item will be positioned.