# how to scroll up when choose some item at item list in android?

Tags: android, scroll

I jave a list of item (linearlayout inside a scrollview where i add buttons vertically to linearlayout dynamically from the java code  ) ? i need when i click on one button the item moves up (scroll up) , to make the item at the first of the screen ??!

Comment: Well thats a pretty different question!

Answer (score 0):

Well I never did that, but from the ListView reference it seems pretty clear that set [setSelectionFromTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) is what you are searching for.

See also [how-to-autoscroll-a-list-view-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804384/how-to-autoscroll-a-list-view-in-android)